# azure dashboard shared user cannot view chart

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-dashboard

I shared a dashboard with a user not in my resource group, and the user can view the dashboard but does not have permissions to view the chart visualizations on that dashboard. I granted the user read role on the dashboard.
Do I need to add read permissions to app insights?

[image: error on dashboard chart]

Thank you.
Sasha

Comment: Try re-publishing the dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to grant access to the underlying resource - [Check this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c41f9668-74e7-42d7-8745-a14748ec6926/shared-dashboard-doesnt-allow-user-to-see-data?forum=windowsazuremanagement).